# Contour lines not plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib

Based on this example: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_lda_qda.html

I'm trying to plot contours on one of my LDA plots.

Here is the code I use for the plotting part:

```
# Get the limits of the graph. Used for adapted color areas
x_min, x_max = fig.axes[0].get_xlim()
y_min, y_max = fig.axes[0].get_ylim()

# Fit the LDA classifier on the new subspace
lda.fit(transformed, analytes)

# Step size of the mesh. Decrease to increase the quality of the VQ.
# point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
# h = 0.02
h = 0.005

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# Predict the class for each point of the space
Z = lda.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

# Plot the areas
plt.imshow(Z, extent=(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max),
           cmap=cmap, aspect='auto', origin='lower', alpha=0.7)

plt.contour(xx, yy, Z, colors='k')

plt.show()
```

It works. Mostly. For an unknown reason, some of the contours are not plotted:

[image]

As you can see at the bottom, there is no line separating the green and blue areas.

Do you have any idea why ?